# Using JavaScript/jQuery, how do you filter a list based on a selection made from a drop down list?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

Here's a screenshot of my app:

[image]

The list of fillers that you see are coming from the database and are all tied to multiple capsules.  I don't ever want to show ALL fillers.  I only want to show fillers based on the capsule selected.  There are 4 capsules that the user can select from.  When the user chooses #0 Capsule, for example, I want the Filler list to change to only show fillers related to the #0 Capsule.  Same for the other capsules as well.

What's the best way to dynamically modify the filler list to only show fillers based on the capsule selected?  Do I want to make a call to my C# method that retrieves the list of fillers and pass in the capsule chosen, which would involve a post-back?  Or is there a better way to do this via client-side?

Comment: Add the capsule type as an `data-*` attribute to the filler items. With this information you can easily filter the list.

Comment: do you want the filler visible at all before a capsule is chosen?

Comment: I'd use a partial with child action to render the filler. on change event of the capsule, make a Ajax load statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make a controller with a method called GetFillersByCapsule(int
   capsuleTypeId). This should return the fillers on a json object.
2. If you're using jQuery on the client side you should write a function that makes the ajax call to this controller method. Bind the call to document.ready and to dropdown change. Something like this:

   ```
   <script>
   var dropdown = $("#dropdownId"); //Declare this first so you don't have to search the DOM each time
   function getFillers(){
      $.ajax("yourControllerMethodUrlHere", {
       data: {id: dropdown.val()}, 
       type: "GET",
       contentType: "application/json",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (result) {
          //Use the resulting JSON here to repopulate the list containing the fillers
       },
   }
   $(document).ready(function(){
        fill
   });
   ```

Comment: Forgot to mention. If you're using regular MVC controllers the GetFillersByCapsule method should serialize the result into a JSON. 

Easiest way is just to make a Web API controller which serializes automatically. Example here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TinyHappyFeatures2ASPNETWebAPIInVisualStudio2012.aspx and here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/344078/ASP-NET-WebAPI-Getting-Started-with-MVC4-and-WebAP